# Schedule push notifications in Xamarin Forms with Azure

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I'm pretty new with Azure. I set up a notification hub in combination with a Xamarin Forms app, this works well with (silent) test notifications. Now I have to schedule these notifications, actually infinite, two times an hour. I can't really find any good documentation about this (except some basic information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-send-push-notifications-scheduled) . What is the best way to accomplish this? Is there a direct way from Azure? Or do I have to use WebJobs to call an API that resets the notifications every 7 days (maximum if I understood correctly?).

Comment: Sorry for the unrelated question: did you use any guide to implement the push notifications? :)

Comment: I've used several guides to implement the push notifications (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms). As said this works well. But nothing mentioned about scheduled notifications.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah I want to create a video on it for my YT channel but found this guide very complex :D But I guess I'll stick with it, thanks!

Comment: It took some hours to implement (and indeed I think it can be done easier). But it works :-).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find you can't schedule anything recurring, you can schedule unlimited, but there is no way to specify a recurrence pattern. With that knowledge you probably want to have some other system in place that just schedules new notifications.

This could be as simple as an Azure Functions that can actually be [triggered by using a cron pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#example) and let that Function schedule the new notification(s). Other ways are of course just as good, but I think this might be the easiest and cost effective one

Comment: I found the cron-expressions also. Maybe I will try that, also looking at Azure logic Apps. Didn't expected it to be that hard to implement some notification scheduling in Azure.

Comment: @KoertHeinen If you have one solution, please share it.